# Is non-stationary the same as heteroscedastic?

Tags: heteroscedasticity, stationarity

Are the terms non stationary and heteroscedastic one and the same? As in they both imply a variable whose mean and variance changes with time?

Comment: What definitions of these two terms are you using?  (There are some slightly different ones for non-stationarity, especially.)

Comment: Heteroscdastic does not necessarily imply that the mean changes as a function of any variable, only that the error variance changes as a function of some variables.

Comment: Thanks. I am using non stationarity to mean a process whose mean and variance changes over time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A process whose mean changes over time but whose variance is constant is *not* heteroskedastic (since the variance is constant), but is nonstationary (since the mean is not).

So the answer is clearly "no".

Comment: If I the error term of a linear regression shows dependence to one variable, can you say it's non-stationary since the mean (conditional on Y) changes? I believe the answer is no, cause it's a conditional mean on Y, but I'd like to confirm my guess.

Comment: @mugen "stationary" refers to the distribution (or at the least, their mean and variance) of observations over time, and without some kind of qualifier refers to the unconditional mean (in respect of earlier values of the series at least), not the conditional mean (the conditional mean of a stationary process might be non-zero, for example, in an AR(1)). So you're going to have to be more specific about what you're saying and what precise definition of stationarity you're using and what is being conditioned on or not. [We also don't "condition on Y" in a regression, but on the x's.]

Comment: @mugen in short... it's not clear quite what the situation you're asking about is, but the usual definition of [weak stationarity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_process#Weak_or_wide-sense_stationarity) doesn't condition on potential regressors; you perhaps might speak of it being 'conditionally stationary', or of the error term being stationary. Perhaps you have something you could post as a question.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 degrees of stationary. The weak form requires mean and variance are kept constant. This means that of 3 **stationary definitions are stronger requirements than heteroscedasticity** because heteroscedasticity means constant variance, without reference to the mean.

A process can have heteroscedasticity. But if its mean is not constant, then the process is not (weakly) stationary.

A stationary process (let's denote it by 'S') implies homoscedasticity (let's denote it by 'H'). So S --> H.

Naturally its **contraposition** is also true. So H' --> S', i.e. non-homoscedasticity implies non-stationary.

But the **inversion and negation are not true**. In other words:

"Non-stationary implies non-homoscedasticity" is not true.

"There exists a stationary process that is non-homoscedasticity" is not true.